¿Cómo puedo generar un RFC en C# .NET Framework? Lo que e intentado es lo siguiente:
1.Esto es mi controlador
namespace WebRFCGenerador.Controllers
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Main
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("VistaPrincipal");
        }

        public ActionResult IrSegundaVista()
        {
            return View("VistaSecundaria");
        }

        public ActionResult Ingresar(E_RFC rfc)
        {
            N_RFC rfc2 = new N_RFC();
            rfc2.Ingresar(rfc);

            TempData["mensaje"] = $"{rfc}";

            return View("VistaResultados");
        }

        
    }
}

//Este es la parte de negocios
using WebRFCGenerador.Datos;

namespace WebRFCGenerador.Models
{
    public class N_RFC
    {
        public void Ingresar(E_RFC n_rfc)
        {
            D_RFC datos = new D_RFC();
            string appa = n_rfc.ApellidoPaterno.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper();
            string apma = n_rfc.ApellidoMaterno.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
            string nom = n_rfc.Nombre.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
            string fena = n_rfc.FechaNacimiento.ToString("yy-MM-dd");

            string rfc = appa + apma + nom + fena;
        }
    }
}

//Esta es la parte de Entidad
namespace WebRFCGenerador.Models
{
    public class E_RFC
    {
        public string RFC_Persona { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public string ApellidoPaterno { get; set; }

        public string ApellidoMaterno { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    }
}

//Esta es la parte de los datos
namespace WebRFCGenerador.Datos
{
    public class D_RFC
    {
        public List<E_RFC> ObtenerTodos() 
        {
            List<E_RFC> lista = new List<E_RFC>();
            string cadenaConexion = "server=LAPTOP-KMVJM4UB;database=Generacion28;user=sa;password=123456";
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

            try
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "SELECT idrfc, nombre, apellidopaterno, apellidomaterno, fechanacimiento FROM RFC";
                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    E_RFC rfc = new E_RFC();
                    rfc.Nombre = reader["nombre"].ToString();
                    rfc.ApellidoPaterno = reader["apellidopaterno"].ToString();
                    rfc.ApellidoMaterno = reader["apellidomaterno"].ToString();
                    rfc.FechaNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["fechanacimiento"]);
                    lista.Add(rfc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally 
            {
                conexion.Close();
            }
            return lista;
        }
    }
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que tiene que ver css aca?? o visual studio?? y que es RFC?? y que le pasa a todo este codigo???
